# Automatic dependency injecting using Scrutor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, scrutor

I have many services in my project, and trying to use [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) for automatic DI instead registering each service manually on startup.cs

**BarService.cs**

```
public class BarService : IBar
    {
        public Bar Get(int id)
        {
            var bar = new Bar
            {
                bar_date = DateTime.UtcNow,
                bar_name = "bar"
            };
            return bar;
        }

        public List<Bar> GetMany()
        {
            List<Bar> list = new List<Bar>
            {
                new Bar
                {
                    bar_date = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    bar_name = "bar 1"
                },

                new Bar
                {
                    bar_date = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    bar_name = "bar 2"
                }
            };

            return list;
        }
    }
```

**IBar.cs**

```
public interface IBar
    {
        Bar Get(int id);
        List<Bar> GetMany();
    }
```

**Bar.cs**

```
public class Bar
    {
        public string bar_name { get; set; }
        public DateTime bar_date { get; set; }
    }
```

**BarController.cs**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BarController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IBar _service { get; set; }

        public BarController(IBar service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            var result = _service.Get(id);
            if (result != null)
            {
                return Ok(result);
            }
            return NotFound("No data found");
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetMany()
        {
            var result = _service.GetMany();
            if (result != null)
            {
                return Ok(result);
            }
            return NotFound("No data found");
        }

    }
```

Adding `services.AddScoped<IBar, BarService>();` to Startup.cs works fine, but not with Scrutor to auto map.

```
     services.Scan(scan =>
                    scan.FromCallingAssembly()
                        .AddClasses()
                        .AsMatchingInterface());
```

I get error

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using `AsMatchingInterface()`, which

> *Registers services which match a standard naming convention*

Which would apply to a match like below.

```
public class BarService : IBarService
```

In your example

```
public class BarService : IBar
```

Does not follow that convention so does not provide your expected behavior

So either refactor your interfaces to follow Scrutor's expected naming convention between abstraction and implementation,

Or use `AsImplementedInterfaces()`, which

> *Registers an implementation as all implemented interfaces*

Note however that this will register those interfaces as singleton by default unless a lifetime is provided.

I would suggest registering them as scoped.

Answer (score 1):

@Vikash Rathee, you could try `AsImplementedInterfaces()`. It registers each matching concrete type as all of its implemented interfaces.

```
         services.Scan(scan =>
                        scan.FromCallingAssembly()
                            .AddClasses()
                            .AsImplementedInterfaces());
```

The result is shown below.

[image]